# C# Open XML setting the chart labels' orientation to a vertical orientation i.e. 45°

Tags: c#, openxml

Is there any way to access the chart using open xml and change the label's orientation to vertical so that it won't look clustered? I am generating eChartType.XYScatterLinesNoMarkers charts using EPPLUS.

[How I want my chart to look:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9W5o.png)

I have came across this answer and tried coxy's solution but getting null reference error for category axis.

[C# EPPLUS setting the angle of the chart's X axis tick labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461385/c-sharp-epplus-setting-the-angle-of-the-charts-x-axis-tick-labels/35491979#35491979)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Comment: Hi AztecCodes, thanks for the guidance. I tried to edit the question. Hoping the question is more clear now